# Autocomplete doesn't fire select function if tab out of input quickly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have configured an autocomplete on an input, with the delay option set to 0, and autoFocus set to true. The source: for the autocomplete is set to an AJAX call.  Typically, if a user inputs a search string and tabs out of the field, the first item is selected.

However, if an experienced user inputs a search string that should only have one match and **very quickly** tabs out of the input, the function specified by the select option doesn't fire, and the input simply contains the search string the user entered.  This is causing an error when the form is submitted, because a valid selection hasn't been made (normally, selection of a match sets a hidden form field to the value of the selected match).

If I put a breakpoint in the function specified by the *source* option to retrieve matches, I can see that it is invoked, and gets a list of matches back.  However, the breakpoint I put in the function specified by the *select* option is never hit when I tab out quickly.

I can reproduce this behavior in both Chrome and IE 11, when running against localhost or a remote webserver.  jquery-ui version is v1.11.4.

Question: is it possible to configure autocomplete to -always- select the first returned match if the user enters a search string and tabs out of the input, no matter how quickly?

Comment: can you provide a working demo?

Comment: I can reproduce right on the jQuery UI demo -- https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.  Just enter a character and tab away quickly.  You'll see, if you're quick enough, that the list of matches doesn't come up.

Comment: Hi, have you ever found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete will be "disabled" if the focus is set out of the relevant input, so you don't have access to the values of the autocomplete if you move the focus from that input.

This solution will work **only** if the menu was triggered (and opened):

```js
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  autoFocus: true,
  delay: 0,
  focus: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).val(ui.item.value)
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

The delay there is set to 0 so there will be no delay, however if your `source` is an ajax call - you will have delay there (and if the user will move move the focus to some other element the result will not be what you are looking for).

I know it's not exactly what you are looking for, however if you work with predefined values it can give you the solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Dekel.  I should have specified that this is with an AJAX-based source of data, so it's not going to solve the particular problem I have -- a user who is doing very rapid data entry.